# Why CMake add_custom_command with DEPFILE reruns every time?

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to write my cmake script as follows:

```
set(OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/generated/${target}/static_init.cpp")
set(DEP_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/input/${target}.d")
 write_file(${DEP_FILE} "${OUTPUT_FILE}: ")

add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_FILE}
     COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} myscript.py
     DEPFILE ${DEP_FILE}
     VERBATIM)
```

I expect, that I will populate .d file during my script first launch and later custom command will be rerun only when one of files listed after colon will change.
Instead command is running during every compilation, even with empty dependencies list. Printing my own sources during cmake run also leads me to constant command rerunning. What am I doing (or understanding) wrong?

CMake 3.18.5
Ninja
Clang

Answer (score 1):

Ninja removes depfiles by default after reading them. This would cause the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that DEPFILE option and target name inside depfile must be relative to build dir, not absolute paths.
ninja -d explain helped me to find it.